# Create every image in the world

Tags: python, image

I am in quarantine and having a lot of free time I thought: since the images are the representation of reality, THEORETICALLY it could generate all the events that have happened, that will happen and that will not happen.
I know they would be practically infinite, but I want to try to create some (very low resolution).
I am trying with a 3x3 but I don't know how to combine all the rgb colors.
This is the code:

```
import numpy as np

r1 = [0, 0, 0]
r2 = [0, 0, 0]
r3 = [0, 0, 0]

v1 = [0, 0, 0]
v2 = [0, 0, 0]
v3 = [0, 0, 0]

s1 = [0, 0, 0]
s2 = [0, 0, 0]
s3 = [0, 0, 0]

for i in range (0, 256):

    pixels = [
                [(r1), (r2), (r3)],
                [(v1), (v2), (v3)],
                [(s1), (s2), (s3)]
             ]

    array = np.array(pixels, dtype=np.uint8)
    new_image = Image.fromarray(array)
    new_image.save('%s.png' % i)

    print("\n")
    print (pixels)
    print("\n")

    ri1=[x+1 for x in r1]
    ri2=[x+1 for x in r2]
    ri3=[x+1 for x in r3]

    vi1=[x+1 for x in v1]
    vi2=[x+1 for x in v2]
    vi3=[x+1 for x in v3]

    si1=[x+1 for x in s1]
    si2=[x+1 for x in s2]
    si3=[x+1 for x in s3]

    r1=ri1
    r2=ri2
    r3=ri3

    v1=vi1
    v2=vi2
    v3=vi3

    s1=si1
    s2=si2
    s3=si3
```

This will generate only a 3x3 image with every shadow from black to white.

Comment: Iterate each color from `0` to `255` in nested loops.

Comment: @Barmar Or `for r, g, b in itertools.product(range(256), range(256), range(256)):` :)

Comment: Either way, do you mean 3x3 images where _each_ of the 9 pixels has a different color, or all 9 pixels have the same color?

Comment: If you are really bored... https://16millionpixels.tumblr.com/post/166278078178/16777216-colors-of-24-bit-rgb-all-16777216